# How do you put a line break in a React string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text file that I'm reading as a string, and then inserting into the DOM like so:

```
//the state gets set with the contents of a text file that has proper indentation
  state = {
    parsedText: null
  }
//in the render function, this is how the text comes in
<p>{this.state.parsedText}</p>
```

When I iterate through the character codes, I can see that the 'enter' codes (i.e., 13) seem to work when I console.log the file (the indentation looks correct). Unfortunately, those character codes don't translate to HTML - the entire string just comes out as one solid chunk of text. So, what I'm trying to do is insert either `<br>` tags or `\n` characters or `&nbsp;` in order to make the breaks work in the HTML.

Here's what that looks like:

```
rawFile.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            let allText = rawFile.responseText;
            for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
              let uni = allText.charCodeAt(i)
              if (uni === 13) {
                console.log('enter!!')
                allText = allText.substring(0, i) + "\n" + allText.substring(i + 1, allText.length - 1)
              }
            }
            console.log("allText: ", allText);
            console.log(typeof allText)
            this.setState({
                parsedText: allText
            });
        }
    }
};
rawFile.send(null);
```

}

The `\n` insertions show up in the text string but are seemingly just ignored in the DOM. Is there a way to make this work? I've tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML and that does nothing.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: use <br/> to line break inline html

Comment: @FrV, answers go down there.

Comment: Oh my gosh, it was the trailing slash that I missed.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same issue. just solved it.

All you need to do is to save the string as array. like so:

```
let text = "this is text without break down \n this won't work but will be one line"

let text = ["this is text with breakdown",
 <br/>,
 "this is the second line"];
```

You can also write utility function to do that for you:

```
const addLineBreak = (str: string) =>
  str.split('\n').map((subStr) => {
    return (
      <>
        {subStr}
        <br />
      </>
    );
  });
```

And use it:

```
<p>{addLineBreak("Hello \n World"}</p>
```

[Here's an example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d1yyxh?file=src%2FApp.tsx) for your reference.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If possible, avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

An alternate solution could be splitting your text into an array then rendering a new `div` for each "newline".

Of course, you would need to come up with a better `key` for the text, as there could be duplicate text - though that is a separate question in and of itself.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
    this.state = {
      parsedText: [
        "Some text",
        "More text",
        "Keep on texting"
      ]
    }
  }
 
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.parsedText.map(text => <div key={text}>{text}</div>)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer here. I ended up using this without the extra DOM element wrappers
```{parsedText.map((text, index) => (
          <Fragment key={text}>
            {index > 0 && <br />}
            {text}
          </Fragment>
        ))}```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a `<br/>` tag in react I wanted to point out that a neat workaround is to use the [`<Trans>` component from i18next](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component).

If you have a variable like this:

```
const customInviteMessageByCreator = "DEMO APPOINTMENT<br/>This room is to test your video room.";
```

You can write your variable wrapped in a Trans component like so:

```
<Trans>{customInviteMessageByCreator}</Trans>
```

And then it replaces the whitelisted html elements that you can configure in your i18n.js file like this:

```
transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ["br", "strong", "b", "i"],
```

I didn't read that this is possible but I was curious if it works because i18next also translates our linebreaks in the translation.json and indeed it does.

I think it is a less hacky and more reliable method than what I've found so far like doing a map on `<br>` where there could be a / before the >. Plus you can whitelist more than just linebreaks. And of course a smarter choice over dangerouslySetInnerHtml.

Answer (score -1):

So you need to dangerouslySetInnerHTML, and as was pointed by FrV, the answer is to insert a `<br />` ... turns out I was missing the closing "/". Whoops. Hope this helps somebody running into a similar problem.